# oauth.io & Twitter email support?

Tags: twitter, oauth

I don't suppose anyone knows if oauth.io respects the include_email parameter on their request - it doesn't seem to be working (yes, I'm whitelisted by Twitter for email access). I'm wondering if the parameter is dropped on it's way to Twitter but that's difficult to debug/prove. Here is my client side code;

```
OAuth.popup('twitter').done(function(result) {
    var oAuthToken = result.oauth_token;
    var oAuthTokenSecret = result.oauth_token_secret;
    //use result.access_token in your API request

    result.get('/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true').done(function(data) {
        processUserData(data.name);
        //screen_name (for twitter only)
        //email is blank, why!?
        authUser(data.id, "T", data.name, data.email, oAuthToken, oAuthTokenSecret);
    })
})
```

Their docs talk about manually creating the request, but that would surely involve manipulating the secrets and signature on the client, which I obviously don't want to do. I'd love to stick with oauth.io, it's working well in all other respects.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug recently introduced in oauthio - I thought it had worked before!

"The last OAuth.io release included some core dependencies upgrade, and we missed a Restify breaking change which was changing the way it parses query parameters in GET requests."

The fix is here: https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd/commit/b2ad616592883b2773b1489e374c65575e319913

Not yet merged and released, but that should happen soon...